# Is my SQL wrong or is it sqlfiddle?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to better wrap my head around PIVOT in MySQL. I made a [test table and query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60699/7) in SQLfiddle but I'm not getting it to work. I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'PIVOT ( COUNT p.[stat] FOR p.[title] IN (p.[title], p.[weight],
>   p.[length]' at line 3

**Table and data:**

```
CREATE TABLE pivoter (
  amount int,
  title varchar(20),
  weight int,
  length int,
  stat varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (5, 'Blip', 13, 5, 'hold');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (2, 'Crog', 10, 5, 'full');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (2, 'Gump', 22, 1, 'hold');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (10, 'Yark', 7, 12, 'fun');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (0, 'Blim', 6, 1, 'full');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (3, 'Fron', 5, 8, 'hold');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (8, 'Xand', 2, 7, 'fun');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (2, 'Xnor', 7, 9, 'hold');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (4, 'Rugg', 7, 8, 'fun');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (9, 'Lint', 4, 10, 'fun');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (9, 'Pawn', 7, 2, 'hold');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (0, 'Undr', 12, 11, 'hold');
INSERT INTO pivoter VALUES (14, 'Call', 1, 6, 'full');
```

**Pivot Query:**

```
select stat, title, weight, length, amount from pivoter p

PIVOT
(
  COUNT p.[stat]
  FOR p.[title]
  IN (p.[title], p.[weight], p.[length], p.[amount])
) AS testedPivot;
```

In case you were wondering, no, the data isn't supposed to make sense. I just made garbage to try this out.

- Is the problem with my query or sqlfiddle?

  - If it's my query what can I do to make this work?
  - If the problem is sqlfiddle, do you know of an alternative?

Comment: can you be more specific than "doesn't work"

Comment: also, what is `pivot`? i don't think `pivot` is a valid mysql keyword

Comment: If you click on the link it should bring you to the exact error and all. But what I will edit it to is I get an error about the pivot and not data returned.

Comment: you should put any errors in the question instead of relying on people to click a link

Comment: It seems you are using [MS Sql Server syntax](http://forums.asp.net/t/1821099.aspx?How+to+use+Pivot+of+Sqlserver+in+Mysql) in mysql. This will not work. The MySQL way is to use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html) statements.

Comment: also i dont think a `for in` statement is valid either

Comment: or the brackets `[]` around field names. I think this is just not at all valid `mysql` syntax, I'm not familiar with others but it seems like hd1 is correct that you are using syntax from some other flavor of sql

Answer (score 1):

The query in the question looks like T-SQL syntax for Microsoft SQL Server.

This syntax is *not valid* in MySQL, for a couple of reasons.

PIVOT is not a valid keyword in MySQL.

And MySQL uses backticks to escape identifiers, not square brackets.